# QGIS Value relation end and Start points while digitizing

Tags: digitizing, lines-to-points

I do a lot of pipes/pits digitization and i am trying to streamline the process. I am attempting to fill  "To" and "From" field when digitizing lines with the IDs from a point layer they are connecting to.

Currently I digitize the lines then post process by creating start/end points, doing a spatial join on the point layers and then conducting a attribute join back on the line layer.

My goal is to fill these details as i digitise. I have played around with the fields widget and using expressions in particular the refFunctions expressions for example:

```
geomnearest(targetLayer,targetField)
```

I have got it to a point where i can fill it with the ID of the first point (from the target layer) the polyline touches (irrespective of if i want the end point or start point).

Is there an expression to identify not the first point in the target layer but the end/start point?